# Grant "Network Service" Read Only Permissions to Cert for RDP via Batch

Tags: windows, permissions, remote-desktop, batch

I'm securing RDP by adding my SSL cert to my Windows host and of course, I'm working on scripting everything. I've got it 99% complete, the only step I can't figure out how to script is relating to permissions.

Eg: https://superuser.com/questions/1093159/how-to-provide-a-verified-server-certificate-for-remote-desktop-rdp-connection/1093160#1093160

1.Start > Run > mmc

2.File > Add Remove Snap-in > Certficates > Add > Computer Account > Local Computer > OK

3.In the left-hand window right-click on Certificates (Local Computer)Personal, choose All Tasks/Import…

4.Locate the pfx file and import it, I suggest that for security reasons you don’t make it exportable.

5.Expanding your Personal/Certificates you should now see 3 certificates, one of which is your site certificate (e.g. mysite.com). Right-click on this site certificate and right-click, choose All Tasks / Manage Private Keys…

**6.Add user ‘NETWORK SERVICE’ with Read permission only (not Full Control), then Apply**

7.Close mmc

I'm trying to script step 6 in this guide. Does anybody have any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods actually that I found to get this working. Of course the better answer came from StackOverflow and not Microsoft.

You can use `winhttpcertcfg.exe` which must be downloaded separately as it doesn't come with Windows. Another issue was it granted `Full Control` permissions when only `Read` was needed. I found no way to rectify this, but in my search I found a better way.

This command will grant `NETWORK SERVICE` `READ` Permissions to all files in the SSL Cert directory:

```
icacls.exe "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\*" /grant "NETWORK SERVICE":R
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/appv-v4/how-to-modify-private-key-permissions-to-support-management-server-or-streaming-server

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttpcertcfg-exe--a-certificate-configuration-tool

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/operationsguy/2010/11/29/provide-access-to-private-keys-commandline-vs-powershell/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678584/winhttpcertcfg-giving-access-to-iis-user-in-windows-7

Comment: I spent a whole day trying to track down a problem where I could read from the Certificate Store when using a console app but not a web app, this finally did the trick!